# php url-encoded vs RAW data in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, php, post, submit, postman

I am posting some data with angular as shown below

```
      var dataReq = {
             method: 'POST',
             url: FILE_LIST,
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             },
             data: { jwt: 'some',date:storedDate }
            }
        return $http(dataReq);
```

I want to know is this considered **url-encoded** data or **raw data**?

I am extracting the data in PHP as follows

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump(json_decode($postdata));
```

This works and I am getting the data in the actual app.

But when I test using POSTMAN I get **null** if the request is submitted in **body>x-www-form-urlencode**

I do get the result however if I submit the data in postman in **body>>raw**

So basically I need to understand the difference the two and how it is handled by the PHP server.